# /boot/config missing for new kernel

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, kernel, boot, boot-loader

I compiled the latest Linux 6.6.9 kernel from source and after installation, when I run `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r)`, I get an error:
`cat: /boot/config-6.6.9: No such file or directory`. The config file is missing.
For the installation, I just copied the previous kernel config in the new kernel source code directory (using `cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config`) before compiling it, then configured it with `make menuconfig`, ran `make`, `make modules_install`, and `make install`.
I have the config files for the previous kernels though.
What could be the reason?

OS: AlmaLinux 9.3 x86-64

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `make install` doesn’t install the kernel configuration in `/boot`. If you want to preserve it, you’ll have to copy it manually, or perhaps use one of the targets that builds a package (`make rpm-pkg` in your case; but I haven’t checked whether it packages the configuration).

Comment: Is there any way I can grep for the enabled kernel options if not using the original .config file I used for configuring the kernel?

Comment: If you enable `IKCONFIG_PROC` when building your kernel, you’ll be able to see the running kernel’s configuration in `/proc/config.gz`.